# Any linter for assembly?

Tags: source-code, code-beautification, lint

Is there any linter that can reformat assembly. I see a lot of things that indicate people care a lot about this (which is to be expected). For example, from [this tutorial](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/)

[image: NASM Intel]

But alas, I couldn't imagine visually aligning code with variable-width labels. That sounds like a lot of no-fun. Is there anything out there that does this?

If it matters, my assembly is written for NASM and x86_64.

Comment: Even, are you sure that you are looking for a Linter  (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)))? This looks like a straightforward code format/layout/beautifier request to me, and there is no overlap between the two kinds of tools. Also, please read [ask]. Could you tell us which operating system you want the answer to run on (update your question to add a tag, please don’t just comment here, as not everyone will read it)? If you don't want to pay, please add the [tag:gratis] tag, otherwise pleas estate a budget.

Comment: I ***do*** hope that you get an answer, though, as such a tool would help me :-)